# firemonkey add item to HorzScrollBox on the fly

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe8

i have a Horizontal Scroll Box item on my form.after run the program i will get a json string that include the list of items that must be in Horizontal Scroll Box .and i must add them dynamically.

for example i have this :
[image]
after run the program in the ? area i must a a new image.

i found the function :
`HorzScrollBox1.AddObject();` but a argument is required for this

i have two question:

1)how can i add the new object to this?

2)can i clone an existing image and add it at the end of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add object: there are two ways - set `Parent` property of children or execute `AddObject` method of parent. `Parent` property setter has some checks, and call `AddObject`.
Depending on control class, child object can be added to `Controls` collection of the control or to its `Content` private field. Not all classes provide access to this field (in some cases you can use workaround, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105713/delphi-set-the-texpander-height/35109511#35109511)). HorzScrollBox has this field in public section.

So, if you want to clone existing image, you must:

1. Get existing image from `Content` of `HorzScrollBox`
2. Create new image and set it properties
3. Put new image to HorzScrollBox.

For example:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.btnAddImgClick(Sender: TObject);
  function FindLastImg: TImage;
  var
    i: Integer;
    tmpImage: TImage;
  begin
    Result:=nil;
    // search scroll box content for "most right" image
    for i := 0 to HorzScrollBox1.Content.ControlsCount-1 do
      if HorzScrollBox1.Content.Controls[i] is TImage then
        begin
          tmpImage:=TImage(HorzScrollBox1.Content.Controls[i]);
          if not Assigned(Result) or (Result.BoundsRect.Right < tmpImage.BoundsRect.Right) then
            Result:=tmpImage;
        end;
  end;

  function CloneImage(SourceImage: TImage): TImage;
  var
    NewRect: TRectF;
  begin
    Result:=TImage.Create(SourceImage.Owner);
    Result.Parent:=SourceImage.Parent;

    // Copy needed properties. Assign not work for TImage...
    Result.Align:=SourceImage.Align;
    Result.Opacity:=SourceImage.Opacity;
    Result.MultiResBitmap.Assign(SourceImage.MultiResBitmap);

    // move new image
    NewRect:= SourceImage.BoundsRect;
    NewRect.Offset(NewRect.Width, 0); // move rect to right.
    Result.BoundsRect:=NewRect;
  end;
begin
  CloneImage(FindLastImg);
end;
```