# get empty parent name in firemonkey if parent is an scrollbox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tscrollbox

how can i get parent name if parent is scrollbox.The following example return empty:

```
ShowMessage(Image1.Parent.Name);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35370868/4908529 You need `Image1.Parent.Parent.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine :

```
Image1.Parent.Parent.Name;
```